# Why is SSJS Platform.Function.ParseJSON not going into catch block if JSON has bad format

Tags: json, ssjs, content-builder, try-catch

I expect this code going into catch block because "hello" is no valid json. But this is not the case. Do you have any idea?

```
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

  var decodedAttachments = "hello";

  try {
        var attachments = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(decodedAttachments);
      } catch (ex) {
        Platform.Function.RaiseError("Failed to parse attachments", true, "FAILED_PARSING_ATTACHMENTS", "1");
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't expect `ParseJSON` function to be the same as the [JSON global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) which was added in ES5. ParseJSON was added by ExactTarget to the `Platform` object in SSJS, because there was no JSON parsing in ES3.

ParseJSON will throw an exception if you don't pass in a string. It doesn't do any JSON linting/validation and will return `null` if it cannot parse.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like this.